# How to run same script in multiple postgres db

Tags: postgresql

Say, I have 5 postgres db. I have to run same alter script against multiple postgres db in one go. Please provide sample if possible. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "in one go"?

Comment: Use automation tools like a shell script to run `psql`, a batch file or Powershell script (if on Windows), Ansible, Puppet, etc etc. (Closevoted: too broad). Did you make any attempt to research this before posting or try to solve this yourself? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have written a shell script to run psql.